# List Form controls in a Combobox

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-2.0

[.NET 2]

how should I list a form controls in a Combobox of the same form(like VS designer does)?

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/TBIDC_uA7NI/AAAAAAAADPM/VAPieyHFzEw/s400/Capture2.gif](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/TBIDC_uA7NI/AAAAAAAADPM/VAPieyHFzEw/s400/Capture2.gif)

I tried:

```
cboObjectSelection.DataSource = Me.Controls
```

but this does not work.

Is there a possibility to filter(customize) this list?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it if you set the `ComboBox.DisplayMember` to `"Name"` but you'd then not get any controls contained in other controls so I think you'd have to get out the names of all the controls (recursively) and insert them into a collection and then pass that as the `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I have put the code in a button's click event, you can modify it according to you requirement. Hope this will help you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                s = this.Controls[i].GetType().ToString();
                comboBox1.Items.Add(s);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Suppose if you have a panel, which in turn contains other controls, you can check just put a condition -- check if the Control.Count is greater that zero...you can use the same logic recursively.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using VB here - and my answer will be in C#, I'm afraid.

Here's my solution, and you can see a screenshot (hopefully, if this bloody link works!) of it working here.

[image]

You need to recursively iterate through all the controls on the form, descending into each one's Controls collection if it has children.

This solution uses a private class 'ControlInfo' inside which a Control instance is place - which overrides the ToString() operation so you can easily customise the text that is displayed in the combo.  You then Databind the combo to a bunch of these after producing them from the Form's control tree.

To use this code create a new form and place a combo called comboBox1 on there, then you should be able to replace everything with this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  private class ControlInfo
  {
    public Control Control { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return string.Format("{0} ({1})", Control.Name, Control.GetType());
    }
  }
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    comboBox1.DataSource = 
      GetControls(this.Controls.Cast<Control>()).OrderBy(c => c.Name).
        Select(c => new ControlInfo() { Control = c }).ToList();
  }

  private IEnumerable<Control> GetControls(IEnumerable<Control> controls)
  {
    foreach (var control in controls)
    {
      yield return control;
      if (control.Controls.Count > 0)
      {
        foreach (var childControl in GetControls(
          control.Controls.Cast<Control>()))
        {
          yield return childControl;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: oh... i forget to mention .NET 2.

Comment: how can I link the control to the selectedItem  of the ComboBox ?

Comment: SelectedItem will be the instance of ControlInfo, which you can cast up ((ControlInfo)comboBox1.SelectedItem) to get at it's Control member.  Or CType(comboBox1.SelectedItem, ControlInfo) is it.

Comment: Assuming you're familiar with what the C#3/.Net 3.5 code is doing here, you should be able to modify easily to build a List() instead.  Perhaps I'm being lazy (if I get time later I'll re-edit!)

Comment: mdeas... Finally `foreach ctrl myCombo.Items.add(ctrl.Name+ctrl.GetType)` seems to have the same effect :)

Comment: Yes it certainly will - although if you need to resolve that item back to the control it was built from (i.e. on a selected item) you will have trouble.

Comment: don't see any trouble: `foreach c in Controls if c.name = selected.Name`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to iterate each item in the Controls collection and add it to the ComboBox's Items collection.  The simplest code would look like this:

```
For Each c As Control in Me.Controls
    cboObjectSelection.Items.Add(c.Name)
Next
```

The issues here are that `Me.Controls` is hierarchical.  IE, a the controls inside a Panel on your form will be missed with this case.  You would need to add all the Panel's Controls to get EVERYTHING on the form.  Which is an ideal application of recursion:

```
Private Sub AddControls(ByVal Combo As ComboBox, ByVal Control As Control)
    For Each c As Control In Control.Controls
        Combo.Items.Add(c.Name)
        AddControls(Combo, c)
    Next
End Sub
```

To get the control back, you have to do this:

```
Dim c As Control = Me.Controls.Find(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), True)(0)
```

The second parameter tells the find controls whether to recurse through the hierarchy of controls.  The Find method returns an array of controls, hence the `(0)` at the end to get the first element.  You should be safe here regarding out of bounds exceptions (IE, the Find method doesn't find anything) because everything in the ComboBox will have been added by code a few minutes ago.

Hope this helps!